# posix thread memory consumption

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

I have a C program creating a detached thread as a child.
Inside of the function I pass to pthread_create I use pthread_detach to detach the thread. At the end I call pthread_exit((void *) 0)

I would like to know if it is normal behaviour that the memory consumption increases after the thread is created.

I did a valgrind check and there are no leaks just 4 suppressed errors.

Comment: Yes - No such thing as a free lunch

Comment: ok, but is it also normal that memory increase is going on after the thread ended and a new one is created?

Comment: Is it a memory leak - Better to ask to chunks of memory from the OS and release them. Have one in the back pocket when you have one to save on the overhead.

Comment: Valgrind says no errors and no leaks possible, so I don't think it is a memory leak...

Comment: Your comment is not coherent with the question text.

Comment: Try using `pmap` before and after your process runs the detached thread to see where the additional memory is.  See http://linux.die.net/man/1/pmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know if it is normal behaviour that the memory consumption increases after the thread is created.

Yes, as

1. each thread gets its own stack assigned. The size is OS setting dependend and could be around 1M.
2. some system resource will be used to manage each thread itself.

Both will be released if the thread ends for a detached thread or if the thread was joined for a joinable thread.